# Appending node issue with powershell/ .NET

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I've been working on this all day and can't seem to adapt an answer for a .NET based solution or native powershell solution to fit my needs.

Here's essentially my problem. I have a few various sets of XML nodes and their children like so:

```
[xml]$parentContainer = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parentcontainer></parentcontainer>
"@

[xml]$parent = @"
<parent>
  <attribute>someattribute</attribute>
  <childcontainer></childcontainer>
</parent>
"@

[xml]$child = @"
<child>
  <childattr>something</childattr>
  <boolval>yes</boolval>
</child>
"@
```

Each of these pieces is returned by an associated class inside of PowerShell and my goal is to eventually combine them all into a single document. So it may look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parentcontainer>
  <parent>
    <attribute>someattribute</attribute>
    <childcontainer>
      <child>
        <childattr>something</childattr>
        <boolval>yes</boolval>
      </child>
      <child>
        <childattr>something</childattr>
        <boolval>yes</boolval>
      </child>
    </childcontainer>
</parent>
</parentcontainer>
```

I've tried a handful of approaches including appending the child nodes as fragments, importing the nodes into a common document, using XDocument classes instead of XmlDocument classes but nothing quite gets me there. Some of my nodes are interpreted by PowerShell as strings so I can't use node based functions on them, the parent nodes are interpreted as documents instead of nodes so I lose the top layer when trying to append them, etc...

What's the best way of doing something like this either in PowerShell or .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[xml]$parentContainer = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parentcontainer></parentcontainer>
"@

[xml]$parent = @"
<parent>
  <attribute>someattribute</attribute>
  <childcontainer></childcontainer>
</parent>
"@

[xml]$child = @"
<child>
  <childattr>something</childattr>
  <boolval>yes</boolval>
</child>
"@

#Add Node child 1 to parent
$xpath = '//parent/childcontainer'
$childnode1 = $parent.SelectSingleNode($xpath)
$childnode1.AppendChild($parent.ImportNode(($child.child), $true));

#Add Node child 2 to parent
$childnode2 = $parent.SelectSingleNode($xpath)
$childnode2.AppendChild($parent.ImportNode(($child.child), $true));

#Add Node parent to parentcontainer
$xpath = '//parentcontainer'
$childnode = $parentContainer.SelectSingleNode($xpath)
$childnode.AppendChild($parentContainer.ImportNode(($parent.parent), $true));

#show result
$parentcontainer.InnerXml
```